# how to add <div> tag data to arraylist in java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i want pass  data /innerHTML to the another jsp page ,so how could i pass it ?is it possible to use arraylist or any other way to pass this large data to another page?
Is it possible add  tag data to the arraylist in javascript?or how can we pass div tag innerhtml to the next page in jsp?

Answer (score 0):

```
i want pass data /innerHTML to the another jsp page
```

This seems wrong approach to me,because the main adavantage of Jsp is actually writing `HTML` on demand,where ever you need it.

Pass the essesntial `data` which decides the `html` to the `jsp` using the `session` or `request` but  passing `html` is a bad idea.

Comment: suresh atta.....actually i want to develop a cart,so while selected items ,added in div tag...when user confirm it,then i have to send these content to next page of jsp?so whts the way to do this?any idea?..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the HTML view data, just pass what needs to be displayed and let the target JSP decide how to render it. For example, if you wanted the target JSP to print a welcome message for the logged-in user; then instead of passing the HTML

```
target.jsp?msg=<div><p>Welcome <b>John</b></p></div>
```

You would pass a request attribute named `user` as

```
request.setAttribute("user", "John");
```

which can now be accessed in your target JSP (using EL) as

```
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
  <div><p>Welcome <b>${user}</b></p></div>
</c:if>
```

In your case, your `Cart` along with its `List<CartItems>`, should be stored in `HttpSession`. This way the shopping data remains accessible to any JSP/Servlet that needs to update the cart.

Comment: Ravi........but cart contain large amount of data...bu how could i add all div data in list??

Comment: @user2598718 Moving HTML data around is absurd. Even if you hack your way into it, what happens when you finally book your order? Would you be able to pass HTML to the backend database to handle the inventory? No. So, you anyways need your Cart data in session so that you can send it to your database to book order details.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div tag div tag. and get the html tags from ouside wrapper div tag.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="what_you_want">
    some contents...
  </div>
</div>
```

$("#wrapper").html() - It contains whole html code in wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Try some Javascript. If you really insist on using kinda abnormal methods (I do too sometimes), you can create an input field of type hidden and put the cart info into that input as a delimited string.

Comment: is it possible to use Json ?

Comment: Probably yes, not sure though; I don't really use JSON. If you write the right javascript code you can give it whatever string you want.